# Uploading files with Flash, FileReference, HTTPS, and Error 2038

Tags: flash, file-upload, ssl, asp-classic

It seems like this issue has been widely discussed, but I can't find the definitive solution to the general problem.

Long story short - I'm trying to use a Flash SWF embedded in an HTML page to upload files.

The relevant code is very straightforward and generic:

```
_fileRef = new FileReference();
_fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
_fileRef.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onFileSelectCancelled);
_fileRef.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
_fileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
_fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
_fileRef.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, uploadDataComplete);

private function onFileSelectCancelled(e:Event):void {
    // handle the case when the user cancels file selection
}
private function onFileSelected(e:Event):void {
    // user has selected the file; upload it
    var file:FileReference = FileReference(e.target);
    file.upload(_uploadURL, "userfile");
}
private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
}
private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
    trace("progressHandler: name=" + file.name + " bytesLoaded=" + event.bytesLoaded + " bytesTotal=" + event.bytesTotal);
}
private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace("completeHandler: " + event);
}    
private function uploadDataComplete(event:DataEvent):void {
    trace("uploadDataComplete: " + event.data);
}
```

The Flash SWF uploads the file to a Classic ASP page in my case, but it could be PHP, ASP.net, or something else.

***When I'm using http://***, everything works perfectly in all of the browsers I test - IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.

I can see that the following events/event handlers are called:

- Event.SELECT
- ProgressEvent.PROGRESS (multiple times)
- Event.COMPLETE
- DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA

However, ***when I'm using https://***, the process fails in IE8, IE9, IE10, and Firefox, but works in Chrome and IE11.

When it fails, the following events/event handlers are called:

- Event.SELECT
- ProgressEvent.PROGRESS (multiple times)
- IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR

IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR returns the following error information:

```
"ioErrorHandler: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2038"]"
```

I'm fairly certain that the problem is not related to the ASP script that receives the file, for two reasons:

- It works perfectly when I'm using ***http://***
- It does not appear that it's even called/executed when it fails. In other words, if the only thing that script does is write a simple log file, I still get the error, and the log file is not written. So, I'm guessing that the Flash error is triggered ***BEFORE*** the ASP script is executed.

I've seen suggestions that the problem is related to my site's SSL certificate.

However, in my case, the certificate appears to be valid in every regard - neither IE nor Firefox complain that it's not valid.

In the SWF, I've tried setting the `file.upload` target URL to:

- a relative URL: `uploader.asp`
- an absolute URL without the protocol: `www.mydomain.com/uploader.asp`
- an absolute URL with the protocol: `https://www.mydomain.com/uploader.asp`

In those last two cases, the URL matches the SSL certificate exactly, but this does not solve the problem.

So, bottom line - is it possible to use a simple Flash uploader when using ***https***?

Your advice and insight is much appreciated!